# Symfony 7 Dynamically Modified Forms

Tags: javascript, php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

i just dont get it to work :-(

I have a FormType as an example now where i have a Select Fierlt with Option1 and Option 2
Now i simple just want, that when i choose option 2 the builder add a new DateTimeType Field.

I want to do it with an AJAX Request if it is possible and i dont want to simple "hide" the fields and then when selected show up, i think thats not the way to go?

```
->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            if($data->getOption() == "2")
            $form->add('datum2', DateTimeType::class, [
            'label' => 'Datum 2',
            'mapped' => false,
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to just "hide" you'll need to use a mixture of PHP and Javascript. What you want to do is described in the "Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms" chapter of this doc [How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms)